# How to have items from different dataframes get consistent colors in a bar plot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'd like to plot a Seaborn bar plot with the color defined by the column variables. Currently, I have multiple dataframes, each for a different month. All dataframes contain `item 1` and `item 4`, but not necessarily `item 2` or `item 3`. Nor do the items occur in a fixed order. So, sometimes, `item 4` can appear first.

Example:

```
       Day Column A count 
Row 1  1   item 1   10
Row 2  1   item 2   11
Row 3  2   item 3   12
Row 4  3   item 4   17
.... 
... 
Row 30 30  item 4   20
```

When I run the following code on all dataframes, item 1 gets a different color in different months. How can I fix this color?

```
plot_day_month1 = sns.barplot(x="day", y="count", hue="column A", data=df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [the `palette=` argument](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) and pass a dictionary mapping the various levels of your `hue` (even those that do not necessarily appear in a given dataframe) to a color.

For example:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
my_colors = {'Male':'xkcd:baby blue', 'Female':'xkcd:crimson', 'Alien':'xkcd:weird green'}
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, 
                 palette=my_colors)
```

[image]